# Invalidating an object reference while another thread is executing a method on it (.NET)

Tags: .net, multithreading, synchronization, race-condition

(I'm interested in the .NET CLR)

What exactly happens when one thread changes the object a variable references while another thread is executing a method on the original object?

For example, say the type `Foo` has a variable 'Bar' of the type `Bar`, and `Bar` has no class-level state (for now at least, I'd like to keep this scenario simple):

```
// Thread 1
foo.Bar = new Bar();
foo.Bar.SomeMethod();
```

In the meantime, before this finishes executing ...

```
// Thread 2
foo.Bar = new Bar();
```

What happens to the method that is (was?) executing on Thread 1? Is everything it needs to complete already on the stack?

Does it change things if thread 2 does this instead?

```
foo.Bar = null;
```

Comment: I assume this is intended to understand the details of the CLR and you already know that you need to serialize access to a shared resource in a real application :-)

Comment: Indeed :) I probably could have even framed this question a bit differently to leave threads out entirely but this was the most efficient way I could think of to ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the call is guaranteed to already be inside `SomeMethod()`, then nothing unusual will happen - `this` is an implicit argument for methods, so it would never use the value of the field (or property, whichever it is) directly.

Whether you can truly guarantee that is another matter.

Comment: And that "this" on the stack is what saves you from being garbage collected in this scenario, should the GC kick in on the Thread 2 foo.Bar = new Bar();

Answer (score 1):

-- edit: corrected confusing sentence.

Well, actually assigning to the variable will be atomic, so it's not like the call will suddenly realise 'oh my I'm null!' while executing .SomeMethod()

What *can* happen, though, is that foo.Bar.SomeMethod() itself will not be called, because Thread 2 will have (maybe) set it to null first; so it just won't execute (it will crash with a null ref exception).

Same applies with your first example; it'll just call .SomeMethod on the new object.

I think you're thinking things may change while .SomeMethod is running, right? No. Nothing will change in there. It will still have the context of itself.

Comment: If thread 2 sets `foo.Bar` to `null` before the method is called, it will not only not execute, it will actually generate a null reference exception. Your explanation sounds to me as if the runtime will just ignore the method call.

Comment: Thorarin: Yes, correct. I admit I worded it really badly. I blame bad coffee.

Comment: Variable assignment is not atomic. It consists of (at least) 2 assembler instructions, a load and a store, and the schedule could interrupt your thread right in between those two.

Comment: Interesting; I'd like someone to confirm that.

Comment: I don't see how the atomicity of that operation is relevant here at all. The actual storing of the new reference *is* atomic, so there is no way there can be an invalid reference at any point in time.

Answer (score -1):

> What exactly happens when one thread changes the object a variable references while another thread is executing a method on the original object?

What happens is that you rewrite your code to properly synchronize access to these fields.